# How to generate python db model with SQLAlchemy for Aurora Serverless and DataAPI?

Tags: python, postgresql, orm, sqlalchemy, aws-aurora-serverless

I've been trying to figure out if there's any way to have ORM functionalities (especially code model generation) for an Aurora Serverless (Postgresql) DB that's used through DataAPI ? Ultimately, I want to avoid using raw sql string queries in our Lambdas.

I tried using [sqlacodegen](https://pypi.org/project/sqlacodegen/) combined with [sqlalchemy-aurora-data-api](https://pypi.org/project/sqlalchemy-aurora-data-api/) (which works on top of [sqlalchemy](https://pypi.org/project/SQLAlchemy/)) but I keep getting errors:

*With dialect:*

```
> sqlacodegen postgresql+auroradataapi://username:password@db-host/db-name
```

> botocore.exceptions.NoRegionError: You must specify a region.

*Without dialect:*

```
> sqlacodegen postgresql://username:password@db-host/db-name
```

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060)

The former seems to hint that parameters must be passed to the call, but sqlacodegen doesn't take any kwargs afaik. The latter just fails to connect and the `psycopg2` tells me it's just not using the proper dialect anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of these two calls are correct. Here is the right way to call it:

```
> sqlacodegen postgresql+auroradataapi://:@/db-name
```

Two main points here:

1. The error indicating `You must specify a region` is correct. The way to specify that region when using command line scripts (such as *[sqlacodegen](https://pypi.org/project/sqlacodegen/)*) is to use **Environment Variables**. [This section](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html#using-environment-variables) of the *boto3* documentation mentions all the variables and their usage.
2. The specific library (*[sqlalchemy-aurora-data-api](https://pypi.org/project/sqlalchemy-aurora-data-api/)*) used for DataAPI uses such a format in their example, and it works fine as is despite being mixed with *sqlacodegen*.

For this problem, the `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` variable should be set to the appropriate value (i.e. `us-east-1`), along with all the necessary AWS credentials (like `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`).